# Debian server (omv) booting into emergency mode, disks not found

Tags: debian

I am encountering the emergency mode message

> You are in emergency mode.  After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to
> view system logs,  "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default"
> or ^D to try again to boot into default mode".

This is the screen I have:
[image: Print out before login]

This is the output of blkid:
[image: Output of blkid]

There should be four disks attached in addition to the main boot disk but my server cannot see these. I suspect this may be the main issue, please see the output of fstab:
[image]

Any help in diagnosing would be much appreciated.
I have tried restarting and physically taking the disks out and back again when the server is off before restarting.

Comment: As output says, add the output of the command `journalctl -xb` to your question. Post it as **text** not image.

Comment: The disk where the partition that starts with `00ee07b3` resides could be missing or dying.